# How to download a single port on FreeBSD?

Tags: installation, freebsd

How can I download a single port from freebsd site instead of downloading the whole port collection?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? Assuming you're talking about portsnap/cvsup, downloading the whole ports collection means downloading all of the metadata files (Makefiles, dependency lists, etc.) for everything in ports, not downloading all of the sources themselves. It will only save you a few megabytes of space -- consider it equivalent to doing an `apt-get update` in Ubuntu.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe +1 for detail for cvsup!

Answer (score 3):

You can install an individual package using the `pkg_add` command, like this:

```
pkg_add -r <package>
```

The `-r` option asks `pkg_add` to fetch the package over the network.  For example, to install `bash`:

```
pkg_add -r bash
```

As with many things FreeBSD, this is documented in the FreeBSD handbook, specifically in the section titled [Using the Packages System](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/packages-using.html).  This is worth a read, especially if you're running a `-release` version of FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanks but I want a port installing. Sorry :)

Comment: OP specifically mention a port - NOT A PACKAGE

Comment: Thanks, @AlexG, for your contribution to this 8 year old post.

Comment: This post shows #4 in Google search

Answer (score 0):

Use SVN to checkout only the directory you need. Say, you need to fetch ONLY **multimedia/vlc** -- then you use this command:

svn co https://svn0.us-east.FreeBSD.org/ports/head/multimedia/vlc /usr/ports/multimedia/vlc

Sure, the destination may be whatever you want, like /home/user/vlc etc.

Comment: This command may be useful in case you have somehow corrupted some of the files in your given port. Like if you edited you port's Makefile and deleted it by accident... That is, contrary to what all clever people do all the time, you DIDN'T save a copy before editing it... I've done this a couple of times ;))